# OS X Mavericks 10.9 and Ubuntu 14 Dual Boot

Tags: xubuntu

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Retina Display that runs OS X Mavericks 10.9. I'm planning to install the newest version of Ubuntu 14 so my laptop will become Dual Boot.

Is there a good tutorial that explains the process of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial useful when I did it last.

http://www.alexvictorchan.com/2013/05/01/installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-13-macbook-pro-retina-102/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please note that it is preferable to add a brief summary of what's involved in that link and then provide the link for reference/attribution. That way if the link becomes unavailable for whatever reason your answer will remain useful. You can edit your answer by clicking the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/480661/edit) link under it.